# ProgressBar with timestamp in millis

Tags: android, timestamp, progress-bar, countdowntimer

I need progress bar with interval from two timestamp values in millis.

For example, I have timestamp of 08:46:11 30.06.2019 and 10:46:11 30.06.2019. But current time is 09:46:11 30.06.2019, so now progressbar should be filled on 50% and going up to 100 until 10:46:11 30.06.2019.

So I have tried next code:

```
private void progressBar(){
            prBar.setProgress(i);
            mCountDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(ltimestampStop * 1000,ltimestampStart * 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress"+ i+ millisUntilFinished);
                    i++;
                    int Start = ltimestampStart.intValue();
                    int Stop = ltimestampStop.intValue();
                    prBar.setProgress((int)i*100/(Stop/Start));

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    //Do what you want
                    i++;
                    prBar.setProgress(100);
                }
            };
            mCountDownTimer.start();
        }
```

But problem is that `int` cannot handle my timestamp in millis and `setProgress()` didn't work with `long` type.

What I can try for achieving my task?

**UPD:** depending on my task I think `countdowntimer` is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your progressbar and CountDownTimer like this -

```
 MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;
`ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);`
 progressBar.setProgress(100);
```

Make your countdowntimer like this -

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

   public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
  }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    Log.d("Time in millis", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
    int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished/100);
    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
   }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    Log.d("Time in millis", "Timer finished");
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
   }
}
```

Call your CountDownTimer like this-

```
myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(50000, 1000);
myCountDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: have done this and instead of (50000, 1000) insert my timestamps - getting empty progressbar

Comment: did I correct provide information in my question? For example, I have timestamp of 08:46:11 30.06.2019 and 10:46:11 30.06.2019. But current time is 09:46:11 30.06.2019, so now progressbar should be filled on 50% and going up to 100 until 10:46:11 30.06.2019.

Comment: upd my question.

Comment: unfortunately no - I am having just empty progress bar (0) instead of certain position

Comment: Countdowntimer does not take two values.  You have to take the difference of two times and run the countdown timer.

Comment: Your time difference is too much,  thats why the progress is also very slow and it is showing empty initially

Comment: Try using a smaller time span like in example,  see if it works,  it will also work for your longer time spans.

Comment: tried use smaller time span - it works. now I am understanding that `countdowntimer` is not what I need for my task - I cannot show position in progressbar in which position depends on future time, past time and current time. Do I need to create a new question instead of this one?